# Redis json on kubernetes

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm

I want to run redis inside kubernetes or on manage service like memory store of gcp but manage service is not providing json support

So is there any helm chart for redis json on kubernetes or any alternate to run on manage redis hain service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a k8s setup that bundles redisjson except for Redis Enterprise. That said, one should be able to modify one of the existing Redis helm charts to include and load one or more modules.

Comment: Yes I am talking about redis lab rejson docker image but is not working with helm chart or other redis lab modules